# Html CSS link fails on Linux

Tags: html, css, linux

I have problem with link css to html on Linux. I testing on xampp windows It's working but I move it on to Linux, It cannot link to my css,js,..

my dir :
html: /review/food/index.html 
  ------css : /review/css/app.css

My code working on xampp windows
`<link href="../css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

So How can I fix it ?

Comment: the css file need to be relative to the url browsing it - not the folder structure of the physical files

Comment: It might be easier to use the absolute path `/review/css/app.css` to the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, maybe you can try adding a `./` first to the route.

```
<link href="./../css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Comment: Hi, I try adding of your idea, but It is not working :(